# Capital gains tax calculations - percentages per year of increase or at sale (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

Purchased house for £100,000 in 2008

Sold house for £200,000 in 2017

The house was let out entirely for the duration of ownership.
My income for 2017 was under the tax free allowance.

Now, to calculate my CGT do I use the data for only 2017 (my income, the CGT rate, capital gains allowance) or do I go back for every year and use a percentage of each year (income, CGT rates in 2008, 2009, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The CGT percentage rates, allowance and income are all based on just and only the year the sale took place.  The allowance is applied just once for the year of the sale.

*(I'm not an accountant but I think this is correct)*